# Track API usage in ASP.NET MVC during development and/or production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, api

My app makes requests to

```
http://www.brewerydb.com/api/breweries/?apikey=<key>&<parameters>
```

but I'm only given 100 requests per hour. I considered recording request instances in the app's database but during development I am often regenerating the database using code the Entity Framework 4.1 so that doesn't seem like it would work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of database would be best.

If your regenerating the DB as you say, then store it in a *different* DB, or if you simply want to store basic info (date/time of hit), then nothing wrong with using XML or even a CSV file on your web server.